# Butterknife 8.4.0 does not find views after re-running the app. It gets a NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, butterknife

After re-running the app in Android Studio `Butterknife.bind(this)` does not find the views anymore. The only reliable solution I found so far is by `Cleaning/Rebuilding Project` and run it again. Then it finds the views again until the next re-run. This is incredibly annoying so far and takes a minimum of two minutes for a rebuild.

I have the following `build.gradle`

```
android {

compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "xx"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode x
    versionName "xxx"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    jackOptions {
        enabled true
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

    }
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE' 
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE' 
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
}

dependencies {
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:2.2.2'

}
```

I am also using build tools `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2`

With `Butterknife.setDebug(true)` I get the following:

```
D/ButterKnife: Looking up binding for xx.LoginFragment
D/ButterKnife: Not found. Trying superclass xx.BaseFragment
D/ButterKnife: Not found. Trying superclass android.app.Fragment
D/ButterKnife: MISS: Reached framework class. Abandoning search.
```

The `BaseFragment` does the binding and `LoginFragment` extends it.
It looks like this

```
BaseFragment import android.app.Fragment;

 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(getLayoutResourceId(), container, false);
        ButterKnife.setDebug(true);
        unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, v);
        initViews(v);
        return v;
    }
```

---

```
LoginFragment

@BindView(R.id.inputEmail)
    protected EditText inputEmail;

@Override
    protected void initViews(View v) {
        EditTextFocusListener focusListener = new EditTextFocusListener();
        inputEmail.setOnFocusChangeListener(focusListener);
    }
```

And the stacktrace

```
  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.EditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(android.view.View$OnFocusChangeListener)' on a null object reference
            at xx.LoginFragment.initViews(LoginFragment.java:51)
            at xx.BaseFragment.onCreateView(BaseFragment.java:53)
```

As I said before the only solution which is reliable at the moment is to do a full `clean/rebuild` of the whole project. This exact structure worked fine before using the `jackCompiler` and I can not disable it anymore. Major part of the code depends on it.

Comment: did you call unbinder.unbind(); into onDestroyView()?

Comment: @Javacoder Yes I do this for the `BaseFragment`

Comment: @MuratK. what about `compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Did not try that, but I canged to the cannary channel and to  `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0-alpha1` and it seems like its working so far..

Comment: @MuratK. glad to hear .Move ahead . FYI ,`-alpha1` is not stable

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Thanks for the heads up. I had hoped that someone would have an idea to solve this with the current version.

Comment: @MuratK. you can post this as answer . #Temporary_solutions

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Yeah sure.

Comment: @MuratK. what problem for old `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2` .

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya That version is too low for the jackCompiler. I need at least v2.2.+. But this issue is getting quite popular on the [butterknife github issues](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/issues)

Comment: @MuratK. indeed .I know .Then try using `2.3.0-alpha2`

Comment: Using butterknife:7.0.1 solves nothing. I was using it when this issue started occurring in my app. I migrated my code to 8.4.0 and the issue was still there. I noticed that this issue was introduced when I switched from 'apt' to 'kapt' for dagger compiler, but butterknife still used 'apt' (or 'annotationProcessor'). After I switched from apt to kapt also for butterknife lib, all views are being injected as usual.  No other action was needed (jackCompiler or AS update)PS: I am not posting this as an answer since OP doesn't use dagger and kotlin, but some folks might find my observation useful.

Answer (score 6):

This is a temporary solution until someone has a better answer or it's released on the stable channel.

I changed to the canary channel and upgraded Android Studio to 2.3 Canary and `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0-alpha1`. Everything else stays the same as in the opening post.

EDIT: I ultimately decided to disable the `jackCompiler` and roll back to Java 1.7. It's stable now.

```
jackOptions {
        enabled false
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

The [github page](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife) says to use `annotationProcessor` but the [jakewharton.github.io page](https://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/index.html) says to use `apt`.

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35016596/apt-dependency-scope-in-android-gradle-what-is-it-used-for/35016697#35016697) SO post, it sounds like it's an issue with the instructions vs the version of the Android Gradle plugin that is used (although I'm using 2.2.2 and still saw the issue).

> **Update for October 2016:** You probably don't need apt and the
>   android-apt plugin anymore. Version 2.2 of the Android Gradle plugin
>   has an annotationProcessor configuration that you should be using
>   instead.

**But you should try this**

Try to change

```
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'
```

with

```
apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already tried to use the `apt` plugin and if I remember correctly you still need to apply the `android-apt` to make it work. But this does not go well with the jackCompiler as it complains. Seems more like an deeper issue between jack and butterknife.

Answer (score 2):

See [here](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/). Please, include this :

At `Gradle`:

`compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'`

`annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'` too.

This may help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missing in project gradle something like this:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
```