# Butterknife not always compiles and produces NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, butterknife

Hello i am facing a very strange issue here. I have used Dependency Injection(Butterknife) in order to BindViews and not write boiler plate code to instanciate the views everytime. Sometimes it works wihtout issues and sometimes it produces `NullpointerException` simply because it does not compile the view i suppose.

My app module(build.gradle):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.androidnative.testproject"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile project(':mylibrary')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.1.9'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

and the Activity that i use:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    @BindView(R.id.bottomBar) BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;
    private Fragment fragment;
    private FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    private FragmentTransaction transaction;
    private RestService service;
    @BindView(R.id.toolbar) Toolbar toolbar;
    private List<DummyJSONModel> modelFromJson = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        ButterKnife.setDebug(true);
        setupToolbar();
        setupBottomBar();
        service = new RestService();
        DummyJSONModelWrapper wrapper = (DummyJSONModelWrapper)getIntent().getSerializableExtra(AppConstants.INTENT_KEY);
        modelFromJson = wrapper.getDummyJSONModel();
    }

    private void setupToolbar() {
        toolbar.setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }
}
```

sometimes i get NullpointereException with the error message of :

```
cannot android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.setTitle() on a null object reference
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Have you set the id for you custom toolbar in your actiity_main xml?

Comment: of course i have it....as i said sometimes it works fine sometimes not...

Comment: I know that my comment is not the answer to your question, but you could give DataBinding a try. It does the same thing. i.e. removes all the boilerplate code.
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html

Comment: well you cannot test some stuff in unit testing after that. I understand your solution but thats what Dependency injection is created for. To write less code and help you with unit testing\

Comment: Have you put: `style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` in `style.xml`.

Comment: what do you do between it working and not working? Are you saying you can make no changes WHATSOEVER and it works then when you try subsequently it doesnt work? Are you making changes to other views? e.g. deleting/creating/changing widgets in views?

Comment: Also, are you using Instant Run by any chance? I had some problems in the past with my resources getting jumbled when using Instant Run.

Comment: This link may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40632518/butterknife-8-4-0-does-not-find-views-after-re-running-the-app-it-gets-a-nullpo/40803213#40803213

Comment: yes i do no changes WHATSOEVER and it works...or i clean->rebuild project and then it works